# sending emails through iteraing foreach loop fetching email column from mysql dabase is best method or not,if not tell me the best way?

Tags: php, mysql

In my database more than 1000 emails there i need to run cron job to send emails to users for that i am fetching all the mails with select query and iterating using foreach loop in that wrote send mail code now my problem is foreach loop executes 13 times only so for 1000 mails only 13 mails reaches to users so please tell me the best way to do this

I worked with this code:

```
public function sendmailstonotverifiedusersAction()
{
    $table = new User_Model_UserMapper();
    $results = $table->usersNotyetverified(0,0);

    foreach($results as $result)
    {
        //echo $result['email']."<br>";
         $code = sha1(mt_rand(10000,99999).time().$result['email']);
        $not_Interested_Table = new User_Model_UserNotinterested();

        $not_interested = array(
            'user_id' => $result['user_id'],
            'code' =>  $code,
            'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
        $not_Interested_Table->save($not_interested);
        $subject = "Verify your email id with Kovida.in";
        $view = new Zend_View();
        $url = $view->serverUrl();
        $body .= "Thank you for signing up with www.Kovida.in.<br /><br />";
        $body .= "Please click the link below to verify your email address. Your account will get activated only when your email address is verified:<br /><br />";
        $v_url = $url.'/user/signup/verify/code/'.$code;
        $v_url = "<a href='".$v_url."'>".$v_url."</a>";
        $body .= $body.$v_url."<br /><br /> If the link does not navigate you to the confirmation page, please either copy the link or retype the link in the address bar of your browser<br /><br />";
        $body .="If not intersted please click the below url <br /><br />";
        $body .= $url.'/user/signup/notinterested/code/'.$code."<br /><br />";
        $body .= "This is a system generated email. Please do not reply to this mail. For any clarifications, email us to: ";
        $body .= "<a href='support@ccc.in'>support@ccc.in</a></br></br>";
        $sending_email = new stdClass();
        $sending_email->email = $result['email'];
        $sending_email->username = $result['username'];     
        $this->_helper->Email($subject,$body,$sending_email); 
         sleep(0.1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your code with problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solution in my mind

1 . add sleep method for 1 sec , so its take sleep after send an email, so its hope it will complete the loop of 1000 insha'Allah

```
foreach($recordset as $k => $value){
    ///your code here 

    sleep(0.1);
}
```

2. add a flag column in your table, when email send mark flag=1 and your query will be

> select * from table where flag='0' limit 0,10

Comment: i think it may be the script execution time in my log file fattel error script execution limits 30 secs